# Get the trigonometric angle given a point in plane

Tags: circles

Given a point in plane as (x,y) get the trigonometric angle for it (that being in range [0,360) or [180,-180)).
Can someone give me a hint please ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\tan \theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \dfrac yx\;\implies \;\theta = \;\ldots\;?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Draw the big circle passing through the point (x,y). Measure the radius. Say the scale 1unit to be equal to radius of circle. If you convert your scale to units, then 
 $$x=\cos\theta, y=\sin\theta$$